# Accessing PHP multidimensional arrays

Tags: php, idiorm

How do I access the elements in these array using PHP?

{ ["step"]=> string(1) "8" ["basePay"]=> string(4) "96.4" }

Comment: In your case, you'd need to use `$array['step']` or `$array['basePay']`

Comment: Yes, worked perfectly. This has always been confusing to me. Thank you.